# Chrome DevTools "console" not showing correct file name

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While developing and debugging with Google Chrome DevTools I have a problem with displayed file names.

any suggestions on how to fix this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8MdP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me.
I have solved it by restarting node.js